# 10001 and in general $10^k + 1$, how can we identify without brute force that such numbers are not prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

I know that $137 \times 73 = 10001 $. I am looking for a properly reasoned approach. 
I believe that there is some general result also which says that all numbers of the form $10^k + 1$ (for $k>2$) are NOT prime. Why? I mean can the general expression for the factors of such numbers be found?

Comment: if k is odd then the number is divisible by 11

Comment: If $k$ is 2 mod 4, then the number is divisible by 101.

Comment: I think there's a sieve thing going on here, with the binary expansion of $k$.

Comment: In particular, if k is odd, then k = 11 * [A095372](https://oeis.org/A095372)(n).

Comment: @peter, I believe you wanted to say that $10^k + 1 = 11 \times A095372((k+1)/2)$ for an odd $k$.

Comment: If $k$ has any odd factor $m>1$, $10^k+1$ is divisible by $10^{k/m}+1$.  So that leaves only powers of $2$.

Comment: questions discussed elsewhere https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/primes-of-form-10-k-1.392807/ also http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7419673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since (as I mentioned in a comment) $k$ must be a power of $2$, you are asking whether the [generalized Fermat number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Generalized_Fermat_numbers) $F_n(10) = 10^{2^n}+1$ is prime for any $n > 2$.  It is conjectured that for any $b$ there are only finitely many primes $F_n(b) = b^{2^n}+1$, and it is quite likely that there are none for $b=10$ with $n > 1$.

According to Wilfrid Keller's
[Prime factors of generalized Fermat numbers  Fm(10)
and complete factoring status](http://www.prothsearch.net/GFN10.html#Summary) , which I think has the latest status of the problem, it is still not known whether $F_{24}(10) = 10^{2^{24}}+1$ is prime.